# Por que é que um cálculo com números positivos dá resultado negativo?

Tags: java, tipagem

Porque é que esta conta `(100 * 22118400) / 44954676` em Java dá um número negativo?

> -46

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(((100 * 22118400) / 44954676));
    }
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/BAw1cQ)

Comment: Pergunta clássica :).

Comment: Porque a linguagem é ruim.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Na verdade, o problema ocorre na expressão `100 * 22118400`. Ele ultrapassa o limite de valor positivo de um inteiro e o Java optou, provavelmente por performance, em assumir um comportamento em vez de gerar uma exceção de *overflow*. Este comportamento é justamente fazer a conta com os *bits* que conseguir e pegar o valor resultante mesmo que ele não seja o que se espera.

Neste caso quando passa de 2147483647 (2 elevando a 31 menos 1), ele muda o *bit* mais significativo que é do sinal, afinal o tipo `int` é *signed*. O trigésimo segundo *bit* é o sinal. Então esta expressão se transforma em negativo e afetará o resto da expressão. Ou seja, ele faz a conta ignorando que existe uma *bit* de sinal e que ele não deveria ser alterando quando uma conta é tentada.

Como o Java não tem uma construção específica na linguagem para estabelecer que a verificação deve ser feita ([C# tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157342/101)), você deve fazer por conta própria, provavelmente criando um método que deve ser usado em todos os lugares em vez do operador. Outra solução parcial é usar tudo `long` que funciona até estourar o limite do `long`. Ou usar o [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) que aceita qualquer tamanho. Em alguns casos um tipo de ponto flutuante pode ser útil. Nenhuma é muito boa. Então a solução real é lembrar disto e ser seletivo quando houver o risco.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Nada relevante, mas no trecho "[...]criando um método que deve ser uado em todos os lugares [..]" não era para ser usado ao invés de uado?

Comment: @JoãoPauloPulga isto, quando é assim, pode editar, eu aprovo a edição.

Comment: Dava +1 se pudesse pela última frase.

Comment: @bigown Eu ia editar, mas o aparecia que para fazer uma edição, tinha que editar pelo menos 6 caracteres...
(E não quis mudar a sua resposta, pois esta muito boa, por isso te avisei)

Comment: Para quem ficar com alguma dúvida veja a resposta do @qmechanik.

Answer (score 15):

A operação *100 x 22118400* resulta num valor que excede a [capacidade](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE) (*2³¹ -1* ou *2147483647*) que um inteiro de *32-bits* pode suportar, o que ocasiona um [**Integer Overflow**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), um transbordamento. Normalmente a [*JVM*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java) não lança nenhum alerta ou exceção sobre isto, segundo a documentação, [**2.11.3. Arithmetic Instructions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.3):

> A JVM não indica *overflow* durante as operações em tipos de
>   dados *inteiro*. As únicas operações com números inteiros que podem
>   lançar exceções são as instruções de divisão (*iDiv* e *ldiv*) e as
>   instruções de resto da divisão inteira (*Irem* e *lrem*), que lançam
>   uma [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) se o divisor é zero.

O resultado **negativo** dessa operação é devido ao retorno vir no formato [**Complemento para dois**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois), que é utilizado para representar inteiros negativos, a documentação cita o seguinte, [**15.17.1. Multiplication Operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1):

> Se um *overflow* ocorrer na multiplicação de inteiros, o resultado são os [*bits menos significativos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit), representado no formato [complemento de dois](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois). Como resultado, se ocorre *overflow*, o sinal do resultado pode não ser o mesmo que o sinal do [*produto matemático*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28mathematics%29) dos dois valores dos operandos.

Considerando o código abaixo:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    // 100 * 22118400 = -2083127296, quando divido por 44954676, resulta em -46..
    System.out.println(((100 * 22118400) / 44954676)); 
}
```

### Representação Binária

O número *100* em binário é representado por *1100100*, e *22118400* é *1010100011000000000000000*. Na [multiplicação binária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es_aritm%C3%A9ticas_com_n%C3%BAmeros_bin%C3%A1rios_sinalizados) obtemos como resultado *10000011110101100000000000000000*, que quando convertido para *decimal* resulta ***2211840000***, o valor esperado. A ilustração abaixo mostra como a multiplicação foi feita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Resolução

Para contornar este problema se deve utilizar um *tipo* que ofereça maior capacidade de armazenamento, [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE) (*2⁶³ -1* ou *9223372036854775807L*) é um exemplo:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(((100 * 22118400L) / 44954676)); // 49, correto!
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/H6fS6J)</kbd>

Se você não se sentir seguro ao usar um tipo como o `Long`, ou não souber o valor que uma variável pode assumir, considere usar a classe [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), *teoricamente* não há um limite, será alocado a quantidade de memória que for necessária para manter a informação recebida, claro que há limites *práticos* como a [disponibilidade de memória](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html), porém é algo bastante difícil de acontecer.

Segue um exemplo de uso da `BigInteger`:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    BigInteger valor1 = new BigInteger("100");
    BigInteger valor2 = new BigInteger("22118400");
    BigInteger valor3 = new BigInteger("44954676");

    BigInteger mul = valor1.multiply(valor2);
    BigInteger divisao = soma.divide(valor3);
    System.out.printf("A multiplicação entre %d e %d resulta %d\n", valor1, valor2, mul);
    System.out.printf("A divisão entre %d e %d resulta %d", soma, valor3, divisao);
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/MVCORF)</kbd>

### Detecção de Overflows

Em versões anteriores ao Java 8, não há métodos *nativos* que auxiliam a detectar *Overflows*, o que cabe a você fazer isto. Uma das formas de detecção é verificar se o valor de uma variável do tipo `Long` está dentro da gama aceitável do tipo inteiro, em outras palavras:

```java
public static int mult(int a, int b) throws ArithmeticException {
    long resultado = a * (long) b;    
    if (resultado > Integer.MAX_VALUE || resultado < Integer.MIN_VALUE){
        throw new ArithmeticException("Integer overflow");
    }
    return (int) resultado;
}
```

E utilizá-lo do seguinte modo:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int valor1 = 100;
    int valor2 = 22118400;
    int valor3 = 44954676;

    int mul = mult(valor1, valor2);
    int divisao = soma / valor3;
    System.out.printf("A soma entre %d e %d resulta %d\n", valor1, valor2, mul);
    System.out.printf("A divisão entre %d e %d resulta %d", soma, valor3, divisao);
}
```

O código acima vai gerar a seguinte exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Integer overflow

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/nazmqx)</kbd>

No Java 8, [foram adicionados métodos](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/jvmlang_numbers) que se encarregam de realizar as operações aritméticas e se houver *Oveflows*/*Underflows*, uma exceção [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) é lançada. Os seguintes métodos foram adicionados na classe [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

```all
Int                                            Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static int addExact(int x, int y)       public static long addExact(long x, long y)
public static int decrementExact(int a)        public static long decrementExact(long a)
public static int incrementExact(int a)        public static long incrementExact(long a)
public static int multiplyExact(int x, int y)  public static long multiplyExact(long x, long y)
public static int negateExact(int a)           public static long negateExact(long a)
public static int subtractExact(int x, int y)  public static long subtractExact(long x, long y)
public static int toIntExact(long value)
```

Segue um exemplo:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int valor1 = 100;
    int valor2 = 22118400;
    int valor3 = 44954676;

    int mul = Math.multiplyExact(valor1, valor2);
    int divisao = Math.floorDiv(soma, valor3);
    System.out.printf("A soma entre %d e %d resulta %d\n", valor1, valor2, mul);
    System.out.printf("A divisão entre %d e %d resulta %d", soma, valor3, divisao);
}
```

O código acima vai gerar a seguinte exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/25P0Kp)</kbd>

### Referências

- [**Detect or prevent integer overflow**](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow)
- [**OWASP - Integer overflow**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Integer_overflow)
- [**Overflow And Underflow of Data Types in Java**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/overflow-and-underflow-data)

---

A título de curiosidade, o [Youtube em dezembro de 2014](https://plus.google.com/u/0/wm/4/+youtube/posts/BUXfdWqu86Q) foi forçado a usar um inteiro de *64-bits* (*9223372036854775808*), depois que o vídeo [*PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (강남스타일) M/V*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0), atingiu o limite de visualizações (*2147483647*, valor máximo de um inteiro de *32-bits*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>Créditos da imagem: [RST](https://rstforums.com/forum/93022-gagnam-style-overflow-youtube.rst)</sub>

Comment: Esperando pelo continua...

Comment: @JorgeB. Editei a resposta, veja se há algo a melhorar ainda.

Comment: Excelente resposta! É por estas respostas que vale a pena pertencer a esta comunidade. Vou manter a outra resposta como certa simplesmente por estar de uma forma mais resumida. Mas acho que as duas se complementam bem.

Comment: A ilustração da soma em binário explica exatamente o que aconteceu.