# O que é checked no código em C#?

Tags: c#, exceção

Vi um código:

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
     checked {
         while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
     }
}
```

Qual a finalidade do código `checked {}` nesse código C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O [`checked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é usado para determinar se o estouro aritmético será considerado como um erro. Então se o valor passar do limite que o tipo suporta uma exceção será lançada impedindo que o valor seja usado inadvertidamente. Por razões de performance o padrão é não emitir exceção e deixar o código correr errado.

Obviamente esse modo só está ativo dentro do bloco delimitado pelas chaves.

São raros os casos que ele é necessário. Ele pode ser útil em casos que quase nunca ocorrerá o problema, mas quando ocorrer é bom que não "passe batido". O mais comum é garantir que não estoure. Curiosamente para verificar antes é menos performático já que há um custo razoável para fazer um *branch* (`if`). Se não lançar a exceção fica mais rápido. [Se lançar a exceção ficará bem lento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101). Sempre devemos evitar exceções até que ela faça muito sentido.

Existe também o [`unchecked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para desconsiderar erros. Obviamente que se não der erro pode ocorrer do cálculo produzir resultados não esperados. Ele só é necessário quando o código é compilado com [`/checked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ligado, mudando o padrão, aí se quiser desligar em algum ponto específico tem que fazer o desligamento pontual. Ele quase nunca é usado.

Os artigos do Eric Lippert, que é autoridade no assunto, fala sobre os detalhes. [Parte 1](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/09/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-one/) e [Parte 2](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/09/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-one/).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VdFs3Y). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOOF8g). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Checked.cs).

Comment: O que é  inadvertidamente?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic de forma descuidada, sem ser o que esperava: http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/inadvertidamente/, https://www.dicio.com.br/inadvertidamente/, http://www.sinonimos.com.br/inadvertidamente/,

Comment: entendi agora @bigown, não conhecia ! achei que fosse erro de digitação.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic advertência -> aviso, ciência; advertido-> você está ciente; inadvertido -> não está ciente, ocorre à sua revelia; inadvertidamente -> forma de inadvertência -> ocorre sem que você perceba.

Answer (score 6):

A palavra-chave [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) é usada para permitir explicitamente a verificação de estouro de tipos integrais de operações aritméticas e conversões.

Por padrão, uma expressão que contém somente valores constantes causa um erro do compilador se a expressão produz um valor que está fora do intervalo do tipo de destino. Se a expressão contém um ou mais valores não constante, o compilador não detecta o estouro. Exemplo:

```
int x = int.MaxValue;  
int y = x + x;          
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Colocar esse trecho em um `checked` bloco impede o overflow, e em vez disso o tempo de execução lança uma OverflowException:

```
checked 
{ 
     int x = int.MaxValue; 
     int y = x + x; 
     Console.WriteLine(y); 
}
```

Você pode tratar a exceção acrescentando blocos `try` `catch`:

```
checked 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        int x = int.MaxValue; 
        int y = x + x; 
        Console.WriteLine(y); 
    } 
    catch (Exception  exception) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(exception); 
    } 
}
```

O [unchecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a569z7k8.aspx) palavra-chave é usada para suprimir a verificação de estouro para operações aritméticas de tipo integral e conversões.

Em um contexto `unchecked`, se uma expressão produz um valor que está fora do intervalo do tipo de destino, o estouro não está sinalizado.

A solução "ideal" seria usar o `unchecked` junto:

```
checked 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        int x = int.MaxValue; 
        int y = x + x; 
        Console.WriteLine (y); 
    } 
    catch (Exception  exception) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine (exception); 
    } 

    unchecked 
    {
        int z = 2 + 10 ; 
        Console.WriteLine(z); 
    } 

}
```