# Como saber se a soma de dois double's vai dar maior que o limite de um double?

Tags: c#, .net, double

Tem alguma forma de saber se uma soma entre dois valores no formato `double` vai ultrapassar o limite da variável `double`?

Exemplo com número inteiro: 2147483648 + 1. Nesse caso ultrapassa o limite de um inteiro, eu não sei se daria uma exceção ou se ficaria negativo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O normal é se ultrapassar o limite do maior número possível no tipo ele virar e começar de novo no menor número possível do tipo, então o inteiro ficaria negativo.

A não ser que peça para a operação ser checada. Aí uma exceção seria gerada. Respondi sobre isso em [O que é checked no código em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157342/101).

Todos os tipos numéricos do .NET possuem uma constante indicando o maior e menor número possível. Então para verificar se **um inteiro** vai estourar precisa comprar com eles. Algo assim:

```
if (x <= Int32.MaxValue - y) {
    z = x + y;
}
```

Só lembrando que se esse valor estiver em algum objeto compartilhado e que pode ser acessado concorrentemente em *threads* diferentes pode haver uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Pra isso existe o `checked`. Em situação assim é melhor fazer a operação e verificar se a conta deu errada através da captura da exceção.

- [Int32.MinValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.minvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)
- [Int32.MaxValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.maxvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)

No caso do tipo `double` é mais complicado e tem o método [`Double.IsPositiveInfinity()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.ispositiveinfinity?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Double_IsPositiveInfinity_System_Double_) para verificar se o valor "estourou". Existem outras técnicas, mas acredito que essa seja a mais confiável. Dada a natureza não exata do tipo não há garantias.

```
var x = Double.MaxValue;
double y = 0;
if (!Double.IsPositiveInfinity(x * 2)) {
    y = x * 2;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7lPLiK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LWIkWS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/LimitDouble.cs).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54610/discussion-on-answer-by-bigown-como-saber-se-a-soma-de-dois-doubles-vai-dar-mai)