# Qual a finalidade do método GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

Estou utilizando o Resharper para automatizar a sobrescrita do método `Equals` e do operador `==`. Um dos métodos que a ferramenta sobrescreveu é o `GetHashCode`:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (Id.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
     }
}
```

Qual a função desse método e qual o seu papel na comparação de objetos no *.NET Framework*? Qual a função da palavra reservada `unchecked`? Por que multiplicar o valor do `HashCode` da propriedade **Id** por 397? (O projeto está configurado para a versão **4.5.1** do *.NET Framework*).

Código completo da classe:

```
public class Class1 : IEquatable<Class1>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Class1 other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Id.Equals(other.Id) && string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Class1) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Id.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Class1 left, Class1 right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Class1 left, Class1 right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A maior parte da pergunta já foi respondida em  [O que é Hashcode e qual sua finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184019/101). Lá diz que é principalmente para uso em tabelas *hash* onde o mais proeminente tipo é o `Dictionary`.

É necessário um código que evite muitas colisões, então precisa usar um número que seja fácil gerar códigos diferentes. Um número primo é bem óbvio, não pode ser muito baixo, nem muito grande para ter uma boa distribuição.

Há controvérsias do número ideal ou se apenas uma forma simples usando multiplicação e `xor` são suficientes. Por outro lado se fizer uma fórmula muito complicado, além de poder ficar mais lento pode acabar tendo o efeito oposto.

O algoritmo deve considerar todos os membros que formam a identidade do objeto e é frequente usar o *hash code* dos membros para formar o código do objeto todo.

Algumas pessoas dizem que foi um erro exigir que todo objeto possa ser *hashable*, e acham que deveria existir uma interface que permita isto onde faça sentido.

[Veja sobre o `unchecked`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157342/101).

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dict = new Dictionary<Class1, int> { { new Class1 { Id = new Guid(), Name = "João" }, 0 }};
        foreach (var item in dict) WriteLine(item.Key.Name);
    }
}

public class Class1 : IEquatable<Class1> {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Class1 other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Id.Equals(other.Id) && string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Class1) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        unchecked {
            int hash = (int) 2166136261;
            hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ Id.GetHashCode();
            return hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Class1 left, Class1 right) => Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(Class1 left, Class1 right) => !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/W5PenN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I25TsH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/HashCode.cs).

[Resposta do Jon Skeet com um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/221800).

Answer (score 5):

O método `GetHashCode()` é utilizado para comparação entre valores de objetos, diferentemente do método `Equals()` herdado e não sobrescrito da classe Object que compara entidades por referência (compara o endereço de memória de dois objetos).

Um mesmo código de *hash* pode ser gerado para dois objetos distintos, ainda que ocorra raramente. A resposta do colega Maniero explica a utilização do número 397 genericamente, de forma a evitar colisões frequentes.

A utilização da *keyword* `unchecked` ignora qualquer exceção gerada por consequência de estouro aritmético (o resultado desta multiplicação potencialmente poderia exceder limites de memória de acordo com o tipo resultante da operação).

Comment: Acho que no mínimo tem algumas imprecisões nisso, pra não dizer que está errado.

Comment: Você poderia esclarecer essas imprecisões?

Comment: Fico a disposição para corrigir qualquer informação... Coloquei a informação que acredito ser a correta na minha resposta. Caso tenha alguma informação ou melhoria para o entendimento futuro por favor indique para que possamos contribuir juntos.

Comment: @MarcellAlves  `O método GetHashCode é utilizado para comparação entre valores de objetos`, não é para isto, na minha resposta tem para que é e detalhes no link. `método Equals herdado e não sobrescrito da classe Object que compara entidades por referência (compara o endereço de memória de dois objetos)`, também está errado, o `Equals()` compara o que ele quiser comprar, pode até ser a referência, mas normalmente não é. `provavelmente uma sequencia interna do Resharper incrementada para cada novo GetHashCode gerado` não tem nada a ver com o Resharper, não tem nada de incremento.

Comment: `o resultado desta multiplicação potencialmente poderia exceder limites de memória` ñ é bem isso. `Todo método Equals que tenha por intenção comparar valores e não referências a locais de memória deve comparar o retorno de GetHashCode para os objetos de entrada` isto insiste no erro.

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções, @bigown. Troquei a aceitação da resposta, mas ainda acho válido o Bruno editar a sua resposta com as correções que você colocou.

Comment: Bigown, o comentário sobre o método Equals da classe Object está incorreto. Tenho certeza que este método se não for feito um override compara endereços de memória, o que pode ou não ser verdade se houver override. Também de acordo com o mesmo comentário a sua explicação dos números primos é mais explicativa que a minha sugestão (coloquei como provavelmente pois não tenho certeza desta parte).

Comment: Sobre o comentário referente ao estouro de memória... sim essa é a usabilidade da keyword "unchecked" que por sinal a sua resposta ignora esta parte da pergunta. Peço que sugira uma explicação melhor para o uso dessa keyword que permita quem lê sua resposta entender o código em vez de simplesmente permitir copiá-lo sem entender.

Comment: @BrunodosSantosBermann é verdade, eu não notei o **não** sobrescrito, me desculpe por essa falha, o resto está errado mesmo. Não há estouro de memória alguma, pode haver estouro aritmético de valor e o bit de sinal ser afetado. Coloquei na resposta. Depois eu posso melhorar alguma coisa, no *link* tem mais informações sobre o cálculo na resposta do Jon Skeet.

Comment: De qualquer forma obrigado, mais tarde farei os ajustes na resposta conforme proposto.