# O que devo observar quando for criar um hash code?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

Ainda falando da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/191260/101) sobre *hash code* não ficou claro o que deve ser observado para produzir bons *hash codes*. Eu entendi que precisa ser um número que não gere muita repetição, mas só isto basta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fui ver o [*blog* do Eric Lippert onde tem uma informação legal](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/):

- ele deve gerar sempre o mesmo código para o mesmo objeto
- se dois objetos possuem características idênticas deve gerar o mesmo código, de certa forma podemos dizer que ele é o oposto do GUID
- idealmente ele deve usar apenas campos imutáveis do tipo, talvez até todo o objeto ser imutável. De fato, é comum o uso de tipos por valor que quase sempre são imutáveis, *strings* que são imutáveis, e mais eventualmente outros tipos imutáveis. Mais um motivo para que o `GetHashCode()` não deveria fazer parte de todos os objetos da linguagem como é o que ocorre por estar definido em `Object`.
- não lance ou deixe lançar exceções durante sua execução, tem que retornar um inteiro sempre
- não faça algo muito complexo, tem que ser bem rápido, evite até mesmo complexidade O(n), ainda que nem sempre seja possível, como o caso da *string*
- vale reforçar que o cálculo deve gerar um número sem um critério fixo, o ideal é que não pareça uma sequência, quanto mais distribuído, melhor
- um dos ataques DOS mais conhecidos é fazer uma *hash table* ter sempre o mesmo dado forçando o O(1) ir para O(n) o que pode criar enormes complicações, então evite o uso de dados que você não tem controle em *hash tables*.

Não são obrigações, mas em quase todos os casos é melhor fazer assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**no meu entender, um bom algoritmo de hashing deve:**</sub>

- <sub>*definir um valor para o protocolo e para a dimensão de dados a serem usados;*</sub>

<sub>**vamos supor por exemplo que quer fazer hashing de seis dígitos com um encoding hexadecimal. deve:**</sub>

- <sub>*fazer uma operação de potência para definir um âmbito de range (que neste caso será algo idêntico a 2^6, ou 6^2);*</sub>
- <sub>*iterar sobre todas as dimensões desse range (que neste caso seria algo tipo 32 ou 64);*</sub>
- <sub>*ao iterar sobre cada um dos indices, deve converter o valor de inteiro, para hexadecimal;*</sub>

<sub>**ao fazer isto, pode obter todas as chaves de permutação desse hash
pode também fazer o mesmo com o protocolo ascii, ou para qualquer outro sistema de representação de dados.**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**uma boa forma simples e fácil de criar um hash code em unix é:**</sub>

- <sub>*usando o comando pwgen, que pode ser usado para criar passwords (que tem de ser instalado na shell com um package manager próprio para o sistema -> homebrew para mac, yum, apt-get, pacman e muitos outros para linux).*</sub>

<sub>***pode ser chamado o pwgen por numa outra linguagem qualquer de backend, usand um método, objecto, etc. para evocar comandos de unix, e devolver os mesmos para a consola do website***</sub>

<sub>**para gerar uma hash com o pwgen:**</sub>

- <sub>*instalar o pwgen no seu sistema operativo usando um package manager compativel com o seu so (brew install pwgen no caso do macos);*</sub>
- <sub>*chamar o pwgen, usando um commando do género: `pwgen 20 1`, que deverá devolver uma hash identica a `Ruzooyae6chiiQuei5ah`*</sub>

<sub>**então, a unica coisa que tem de fazer é descobrir qual a forma de evocar comandos de shell a partir de c#, evocar o comando pwgen e armezenar o output numa variável que vai depois usar algures no programa. a resposta a algo identico poderá ser encontrada aqui:**</sub>

- <sub>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string</sub>

Comment: forneça um exemplo de como gerar o hash por favor, assim todos aprendemos.