# Para um algoritmo de hash, é interessante ter um seed?

Tags: algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, hash, ciência-da-computação

Deixa-me explicar melhor.

Para melhorar a segurança ou até obter outros efeitos, em algum cenário de nicho, eu penso se seria interessante semirandomizar a geração do código de *hash* e assim em cada execução a ordem dos elementos na tabela que é montada com esse *hash* deve ser diferente, mesmo que sejam os mesmos dados.

Obviamente que isso só mudaria a cada execução e não em cada instância, e principalmente em cada adição de um novo elemento. Só para deixar claro para quem não tem domínio do assunto.

Então você tem uma fórmula padrão, mais um termo que já costuma ser usado na fórmula (o *seed*, se é que podemos chamar assim) e ele seria determinado no início de cada execução. Poderia ser até dentre uma lista de números pré-definidos e não algo geral, assim não atrapalharia a chave ser ruim e gerar muitas colisões.

Garantindo que não é tão determinístico assim, alguns tipos de ataque podem ser minimizados. [Nada relacionado com criptografia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162369/101).

Não preciso dizer que este código não seria usado para persistência e nenhum *hash* deveria.

Mas não consigo pensar em todas as implicações disso. Qual seria a justificativa contra ou a favor? Estou pensando algo errado?

Também seria legal saber se você já fez ou viu algo assim, e a motivação.

Já que obviamente eu não tenho todo o domínio do assunto, se houver dúvidas estou disposto a esclarecer nos comentário e editar aqui.

Para ver mais:

- [Como armazenar hash em um banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579619/101)
- [O que devo observar quando for criar um hash code?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191766/101)
- [Qual seria um um bom algoritmo de cálculo hash para usar em uma tabela de espalhamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356435/101)
- [O que é Hashcode e qual sua finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184019/101)

Comment: Não sei todos os detalhes, mas sei que [Python faz isso com hash de strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27522626) <- na resposta aceita tem um [link que explica a vulnerabilidade](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html) que é evitada com o uso do seed (que também não conheço o suficiente pra detalhar em uma resposta).

Comment: Para ajudar: https://lwn.net/Articles/474912/. Também tem informação interessante mesmo não respondendo a questão: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash.