# Devo utilizar os tipos ushort, uint e ulong sempre que o número for ser igual ou maior que 0?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

É uma boa prática ou existe algo da Microsoft recomendando o uso de `ushort`, `uint` e `ulong` sempre que eu tiver certeza que o valor será igual ou maior que 0?

Posso ganhar alguma vantagem utilizando eles ao invés do tradicionais `short`, `int` e `long`? (Além de não ser possível receber um número menor que 0).

Um exemplo seria um método que realizasse a geração de um nome de usuário aleatório, e fosse possível informar o comprimento máximo:

```
public static string GenerateUsername(int maxLength) {...}
```

Neste caso eu sempre sei que o comprimento máximo não será menor que 0, então eu deveria utilizar `uint` ao invés de `int`?

Minha dúvida surgiu principalmente porque acredito nunca ter visto o uso destes tipos em *frameworks*, bibliotecas, etc...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Não, esses tipos existem essencialmente para comunicação de baixo nível com o sistema operacional ou outros serviços que exijam estes tipos.

Todo *framework*, exceto quando está fazendo o citado anteriormente, é todo projetado para trabalhar com os tipos sinalizados.

Os tipos não sinalizados realmente não podem ter um número negativo armazenado nele, mas nada garante que se atribua um número negativo para ele, o que causará uma perda de dados e não terá o resultado esperado (em [contexto `unchecked`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157342/101), o C# protege o uso indevido por padrão). Nem pense nesses tipos como números naturais positivos, eles não são isso.

Um nome de usuário com 4 bilhões de caracteres? Espero que não. Um `byte` é suficiente, e esse tipo é sinalizado porque quase sempre quando só quer 1 byte de capacidade, quer ele inteiro. Há quem reclame dessa decisão da linguagem.

Se fosse outro exemplo que faz sentido o `int` permitiria 2 bilhões de tamanho. Quase sempre isso é suficiente, tanto que as coleções do .NET usam um `int` como *length* (por padrão, tem como usar o `long`). Se precisa mais que 2 bilhões provavelmente precisa bem mais que 4 bilhões, e aí um `long` é mais adequado. É muito raro precisar mais que 2 bilhões e menos de 4. Se isso for necessário o `long` ainda é a melhor solução. A perda de 4 bytes não costuma ser um problema. Se for um problema, aí o `uint` pode ser usado, mas com muito cuidado e se prepare para ter outros problemas se comunicando com o resto da aplicação que não espera este tipo.

Só porque o domínio apresentado não permite valor menor que 0 não é motivo para usar `uint`.

Se usar o `uint` sozinho não tem tanto problema, o caldo entorna quando começa misturar ele com o tipo sinalizado, as regras de promoção começam ficar complicadas.

Em C é bem mais usado porque é uma linguagem que faz mais coisas de baixo nível. Embora o uso acaba se valendo até mais em tipos de tamanho fixo já que o padrão do C é ter tipos com tamanho dependente da plataforma. Em C# o uso é extremamente raro, e quase todos os poucos casos é por causa de interoperabilidade.

Não é o caso de C#, hoje, mas tem linguagens que fazem um uso "esperto" em certas situações do número negativo onde se espera só positivos.

As regras de uma linguagem não são as mesmas de outra, o que complica um pouco mais.

Por incrível que pareça lidar um `unsigned` costuma ser mais lento nas principais arquiteturas de processadores, assim como `short` pode ser mais lento que `int`.

Se bem que hoje economizar memória é mais importante, as pessoas falam bobagem quando acham que memória não é problema hoje em dia. O processador típico hoje tem só 4, 6 ou 8MB, em mobile nem isso, e é uma memória meio lenta, a rápida tem 32 ou 64KB. RAM é um auxílio para armazenar grandes volumes de dados que não cabem no processador, para fazer algo ser rápido o dado deve estar no processador, isso dá muito mais performance que economizar alguns ciclos de processamento puro.

Mas não tente fazer economia sem testar muito bem em vários cenários, e só se precisar muito, e souber de todos os detalhes que podem mudar. Ou seja, é o tipo de otimização que não é para o bico de quase nenhum programador.

Antes de ver o exemplo no Fiddle anote os resultados que espera que este código imprimirá:

```
var x = 0u;
System.Console.WriteLine(x - 1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QWefWw). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5XR6at). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Unsigned.cs).

Você acertou todos os resultados? Tem certeza que sempre acertará todos? Sabe todas as regras? Nem eu sei :)

Experimente passar um `int` onde se espera um `uint`. Tem solução, mas é o ideal ou fica parecendo gambiarra por uma decisão errada antes?

Estes tipos [sequer fazem parte da CLS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.clscompliantattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Se quer um tipo que garanta só positivos, escreva um que faça isto e que interaja bem com todos os outros tipos numéricos, incluindo aqueles que não parecem ser tão numéricos assim, como [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Por isso que sempre falo que programação é mais complicado do que parece, e que bom que é assim, não seria divertido se não fosse :) Por sorte algumas pessoas procuram aprender todos os detalhes. Por azar de todos a maioria considera que só aprender o superficial é suficiente.

É ótimo ter o tipo na linguagem para os casos onde ele é necessário, mas não é para usar sem motivo.

Comment: Estou tão acostumado com `int`, que infelizmente as vezes nem percebo que o utilizo sem necessidade =/