# Quando se realiza um cálculo em C#, o tipo primitivo da variável é mantido no resultado?

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, números

Estou criando uma aplicação simples em C# para calcular algumas informações de voo, na qual possui uma classe chamada `Calculator` contendo os seguintes métodos:

```
public static float GetDistance(ushort height) {
    return height * 3 / 1000;
}

public static uint GetVerticalSpeed(ushort groundSpeed) {
    return groundSpeed * 10 / 2;
}
```

Em ambos os métodos, eu defini os parâmetros como sendo do tipo primitivo `ushort`, pois eles devem ser iguais ou maiores que zero, e devem ter um determinado limite, já que nenhuma aeronave voa acima de 65536 pés de altitude e acima de 65536 nós de velocidade — que é o valor máximo desse tipo primitivo.

Já o tipo primitivo do retorno dos métodos é diferente. No primeiro método, o retorno é `float`, pois preciso obter os decimais do resultado. Já no segundo método, o retorno é `uint`, pois o resultado pode ser maior que 65535.

O problema é que mesmo tendo o tipo primitivo de retorno "compatível" com o resultado máximo que o método pode retornar, o compilador ainda gera o seguinte erro para o segundo método:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Além disso, no primeiro método, o resultado retornado é sempre um inteiro — sem ponto flutuante — mesmo quando deveria ser um número real.

Isso me leva a pensar que o problema do meu código não está no retorno dos métodos, mas sim na linha do cálculo. Eu escrevi os métodos achando que o cálculo iria retornar um valor, cujo tipo primitivo fosse correspondente ao resultado. Mas parece que não é isso o que ocorre.

Dito isso, a minha dúvida é:

- As operações aritméticas em C# mantém o tipo primitivo da variável utilizada no resultado?
- Se sim, como isso ocorre internamente e o que eu deveria fazer para que o resultado tenha um tipo primitivo diferente da variável?

Comment: sim, o compilador não sabe como fazer isso, precisa por um *cast* ai no código para converter para o tipo desejado, nesse caso `uint`.Sobre sua pergunta, o tipo da variável é imutável, se ela é `int` por exemplo, sempre vai ser `int`, e assim por diante. E segunda pergunta como mencionei, só fazer um *cast* e converter para o tipo desejado

Comment: Só complementando, o typecast explicito `return (uint)(groundSpeed * 10 / 2);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No caso da divisão em C#, o compilador irá basear o tipo da avaliação a partir do tipo dos operandos.

Se todos os operandos da divisão possuirem um tipo inteiro, então o operador `/` retornará como resultado a **divisão inteira** de seus dois operandos.

Por exemplo:

```
5 / 2      //=> 2
```

É avaliado pelo C# como `2`. Como os dois operandos são inteiros, ocorre a divisão inteira.

Se você quiser operar uma "divisão de ponto flutuante", deve fazer um *cast* explícito de pelo menos um dos operandos. Pode-se utilizar a [sintaxe literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals):

```
5f / 2      //=> 2.5
5 / 2f      //=> 2.5
5f / 2f     //=> 2.5
```

Ou utilizar a [sintaxe de *cast*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions):

```
(float)5 / 2            //=> 2.5
5 / (float)2            //=> 2.5
(float)5 / (float)2     //=> 2.5
```

Claro, também daria para fazer o *cast* para `double` ou `decimal`, se necessário.

---

Em relação ao segundo método e sobre a conversão de `uint` para `int`:

> O problema é que mesmo tendo o tipo primitivo de retorno "compatível" com o resultado máximo que o método pode retornar, o compilador ainda gera o seguinte erro para o segundo método:

Não diria que é plenamente compatível. Afinal, o resultado da expressão (inferido pelo compilador) é `int`. E, decerto, `int` nem sempre será compatível a `uint`.

Desse modo, o compilador exige que você seja explícito ao fazer esse tipo de *cast*. Como *pode haver* perda de dados (digamos que você converta um `int` negativo para `uint`, daria problema), você precisa mostrar que "está ciente disso".

Portanto, precisa fazer assim:

```
public static uint GetVerticalSpeed(ushort groundSpeed)
{
    return (uint)(groundSpeed * 10 / 2);
}
```

Ou simplesmente garanta que os números ao final são `uint` para que o compilador avalie o tipo da expressão para `uint`. Assim:

```
public static uint GetVerticalSpeed(ushort groundSpeed)
{
    return groundSpeed * (uint)10 / (uint)2;
}
```

---

Mas, de modo geral, utilizar tipos numéricos *unsigned* em resposta a alguma regra do domínio (como o fato de que um objeto não pode ter velocidade negativa) pode não justificar o uso de um tipo *unsigned*.

Conforme explicado em [Devo utilizar os tipos ushort, uint e ulong sempre que o número for ser igual ou maior que 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284886/69296), pensar em tipos numéricos sem sinal como um "subconjunto" dos [números naturais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_natural) nem sempre é uma boa ideia, visto que o tipo, por si só, *pode não* dar garantias do valor armazenado.

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284886/69296) também tem alguns detalhes a mais.

Em suma, utilizar `int` (ou talvez um `short` mesmo) no seu código provavelmente simplificaria as coisas (além de tornar alguns *casts* desnecessários). Se você precisa de garantir um "limite de velocidade" (em resposta a alguma regra de domínio), trate isso explicitamente no seu código.

Comment: Valeu Luiz! Ah, e aproveitando. Estou há um tempo sem entrar no Discord porque minha net foi cortada e não tenho prazo de quando ela vai voltar ;(

Comment: Luiz, eu escrevi a linha utilizando a primeira forma que você apresentou, mas sem isolar o cálculo com os parênteses, dessa forma: `return (uint) groundSpeed * 10 / 2`. Ainda assim, ele funcionou. Por que?

Comment: O compilador vai entender o _cast_ que você está fazendo do mesmo jeito. Esse comportamento é esperado.