# Erro "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero" no java

Tags: java, lógica

Estou tentando resolver um exercício, mas continua dando erro. Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class mod_IV_ex_1 {
static int fatorial(int numero){
    int fatorial = 0;
    if (numero == 0) {
        fatorial = 1;
        return fatorial;
    } else{
        for (int i = 2; i <= numero; i++) {
            fatorial *= i;
        }
        return fatorial;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("EXERCICIO 1, MODULO IV");
    int j, i;
    
    double fracao = 0;
    double soma = 0;

    for (i = 100; i >= 80; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
            fracao = i / fatorial(j);
            soma += fracao;
            System.out.printf("%d / %d + ", i, fatorial(j));
        }

    }
    System.out.printf(" = %.2f\n", soma);
}
```

}

E o erro que aparece é o seguinte:

[image: java]

Comment: O problema é que o fatorial não pode começar por 0, tem que ser por 1, até porque a multiplicação por 0 dá 0. Mas dará outro problema de estou do `int`, terá que usar um `BigInteger`, leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58533/101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na função que calcula o fatorial.

Repare que `fatorial` começa com zero. Se o número for, digamos, `2`, ele entra no `else`, e dentro do `for` você multiplica `fatorial` por `i`. Mas como `fatorial` é zero, multiplicá-lo por qualquer número resultará em zero. Então dentro do *loop* você está tentando fazer uma divisão por zero, o que dá erro.

Então na verdade o fatorial deve começar em 1, não em zero:

```
static double fatorial(int numero) {
    double fatorial = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= numero; i++) {
        fatorial *= i;
    }
    return fatorial;
}
```

Repare que nem precisa do `if`, pois se o número for zero, ele não entra no `for` (já que a condição `i <= numero` será falsa) e será retornado `1`.

E mudei o tipo de `int` para `double`, porque o fatorial de 17 estoura o tamanho máximo de um `int` (que é 2147483647), e aí ocorre um *overflow* e a conta fica errada.

E o cálculo também está errado. Ao fazer um *loop* dentro do outro, na verdade você está fazendo `100 / 0! + 100 / 1! + ... + 100 / 20! + 99 / 0! + 99 / 1! ...`. Você só precisa fazer um *loop*, e ir mudando `i` e `j` ao mesmo tempo:

```
double soma = 0;
for (int i = 100, j = 0; i >= 80; i--, j++) {
    soma += i / fatorial(j);
    System.out.printf("%d / %f + ", i, fatorial(j));
}
```

---

Mas na verdade não precisa de um método para calcular o fatorial (a menos que seja exigência do exercício). Pois quando você calcula, por exemplo, 3!, você já multiplicou 2 e 3. Na próxima iteração, você vai calcular 4! e vai ter que multiplicar novamente 2 e 3, para depois multiplicar por 4.

Nesse caso, é melhor guardar o último fatorial calculado e só multiplicar o que falta:

```
double soma = 0;
double denominador = 1;
for (int i = 100, j = 0; i >= 80; i--, j++) {
    soma += i / denominador;
    System.out.printf("%d / %f + ", i, denominador);
    if (j > 0)
        denominador *= (j + 1);
}
```

Comment: Nossa, deu certo, muito obrigada! E tinha mais problemas que tinha percebido, eu nem sabia que podia juntar o i e j no for. =)